# What is chunked[chunked.length - 1]? in this block of code

Tags: javascript

I found this block of code on search of other solutions for array chunk in js, but i stumble on figuring out on this part: `const last = chunked[chunked.length - 1];` ? can someone explain what it does?

```
function chunk(array, size) {
      const chunked = [];

      for (let element of array) {
        const last = chunked[chunked.length - 1];

        if (!last || last.length === size) {
          chunked.push([element]);
        } else {
          last.push(element);
        }
      }

      return chunked;
    }

    chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 3)

    result:
    [[ 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Comment: `someArray[someArray.length - 1]` returns the last element of `someArray` (or `undefined` if `someArray` is empty)

Comment: `chunked` is an array. Arrays have length. So `chunked.length` is a number, namely the number of elements inside `chunked`. But arrays are zero-based, so the first element is at index 0. So the last element of the array is inside the index of length - 1. So `chunked[ chunked.length - 1 ]` will find the last element inside `chunked`.

Comment: Finally get it, if last element is equal to the given size push those element into chunked.